# HTML getting content to center dead center between header and footer

Tags: html, css

I'm sure this is a super simple issue, but I just can't seem to get this to work. I've tried plenty of tweaks here and there including playing around with the CSS for `html` and `body` but not getting the result I'm expecting.

Basically, I am looking to get the content on **every page** to center between the header (fixed) and the footer (absolute). Below is an example of one of these pages, along with the header and the footer.

Below is **/app/views/users/edit.html.erb**

```
html {
   margin-top: 60px;
}

</style>

<% provide(:title, "My Profile") %>
<h1><center>My Profile</center></h1>

<div class="gravatar_edit">
      <center><%= gravatar_for @user %>
      <br><a href="http://gravatar.com/emails" target="_blank">change</a></center>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %><br>

      <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is my **/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb**

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

html{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

body{
    padding: 80px;
}

header {
    padding: 10px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #fff;
    min-width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
}

.nav {
    background: #232323;
    height: 60px;
    *display:inline;
    *zoom:1;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}

.nav li a {
    font-size: 14px; 
    color: white;
    display: block;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 26px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #2e2e2e;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
}

#search {
    width: 357px;
    margin: 4px;
}
#search_text{
    width: 297px;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial;
    border: 0 none;
    height: 52px;
    margin-right: 0;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    background: #494949;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 0.15s;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color: white;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color: white;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color: white;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color: white;
}
#search_text:focus {
    background: #5a5a5a;
}

#options a{
    border-left: 0 none;
}

.subnav {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110%;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all 0.1s;
    background: #232323;
}
.subnav li {
    float: none;
}
.subnav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2e2e2e;
}
#options:hover .subnav {
    visibility: visible;
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <ul class= "nav">
      <li><a class="active" href="/home">Home</a></li>
      <% if logged_in? %>
        <li><%= link_to "Profile", edit_user_path(current_user.id) %></li>
      <%end%>
      </li>
      <li><%= link_to "Contact", new_inquire_path, method: :get %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path, method: :delete %></li>
      <li id= "search">
        <form action= "" method= "get">
            <input type="text" name="search_text" id= "search_text" placeholder="Search Page"/>
            <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  </body>
```

Below is my **/app/views/layouts/_footer.html.erb**

```
<head>
<style>

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 300px;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

footer p {
    text-align: center; 
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <footer>
            <small>
            Database BETA 
            </small>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Seann was partially correct in that everything should be wrapped in a container.

However, this css is what fixed it:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
   margin-top: 60px; /*change this to the height of your header*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap in a containter and then do something like this for the container's css:

```
top:50%;
transform:translateY(-50%);
```